# I need to view loading indicator before viewing my partial view

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax

this is my code html.

```
<input type="button" name="signup_submit" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#panel" onclick="generate('#report', '_DailyReport', 'Reports');" class="btn btn-primary toggle" id="btnSubmit" value="Generate"  />
```

partial view div

```
<div class="panel panel-default" id="report" style="display:none">
```

this is my ajax to view the partial view

```
var generate = function (editHtmlInnerId, EditActionName, EditcontrollerName) {
    debugger;
$.ajax({
    url: "/" + EditcontrollerName + "/" + EditActionName,
    type: $("#addNewUserForm").attr('method'),
    data: $("#addNewUserForm").serialize(),
    success: function (result) {

        $(editHtmlInnerId).html(result);
        $(editHtmlInnerId).show();

       },
    error: function () {
    }
});
};
```

so i need to display loading indicator until the data loads in the partial view. my partial view contains a table that generates data.

Comment: What's the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display your loading indicator before your ajax call, and then hide it in "success" and "error" event :

```
var generate = function (editHtmlInnerId, EditActionName, EditcontrollerName) {
    debugger;

// Shows div with loading stuff.
$("#divLoading").show();

$.ajax({
    url: "/" + EditcontrollerName + "/" + EditActionName,
    type: $("#addNewUserForm").attr('method'),
    data: $("#addNewUserForm").serialize(),
    success: function (result) {

        // Hides loading indicator.
        $("#divLoading").hide();

        $(editHtmlInnerId).html(result);
        $(editHtmlInnerId).show();

       },
    error: function () {

        // Hides loading indicator.
        $("#divLoading").hide();

    }
});
```